# How to find a model using pivot table data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pivot

i have a tournament and a club model.i use many to many relationship between them.now  i want to find a club model using pivot table.

i've tried this:

```
$tournament = Tournament::find(1);
    $club = $tournament->clubs->wherePivot('team_as_1','1');
    return $club;
```

but it shows:Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::wherePivot does not exist.

My tournament model:

```
public function clubs(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Club','tbl_club_tournament')->withPivot('team_as_1','team_as_4','team_as_5','team_as_6');
    }
```

My club model:

```
public function tournament(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tournament','tbl_club_tournament')->withPivot('team_as_1','team_as_4','team_as_5','team_as_6');
    }
```

i want to find a club where team_as_1 = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Below

```
$tournament = Tournament::find(1);
$clubs = $tournament->clubs()->wherePivot('team_as_1','1')->get();
return $clubs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
$tournament = Tournament::find(1);
    $club = $tournament->clubs()->wherePivot('team_as_1','1')->get();
    return $club;
```

With the current approach you're calling method wherePivot on a collection (but that method doesn't exist on the collection class), however by calling the function $tournament->clubs(), that returns a query builder object on which you can call wherePivot()

Edit:
Seems you only need one item, so you should probably do

```
$club = $tournament->clubs()->wherePivot('team_as_1','1')->first();
```

Comment: it doesn't work..it says :Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

```
return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Club', 'App\Tournament');
```